# Redis online data structure change from set to zset

Tags: redis

Say, we have 500GB online data that all of them have been saved in redis as set with nearly 10^8 keys.
Unfortunately, the set data structure is no longer workable for the system and we want to migrate
all the sets into zsets with all the same initial scores (like timestamp).

I found that we can use `zinterscore new_zset 1 orig_set weights timestamp` command to achieve the migration.
Does this suppose that we need to scale the memory volume up to 1.0 ~ 1.5TB temporarily for the above conversion.
But how long will this take? Has anyone run into the same situation like this(online data structure change)? 
Or fundamentally, should I do this? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: To estimate the time, measure it in a testing environment before doing it in production.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to use `ZINTERSTORE` to do the job. As you've already mentioned, it will cost too much extra memory, and block your Redis for a long time, since your data set is very large.

Instead, you should use `SSCAN` command to iterate the *SET*, and use `ZADD` command to put items into *SORTED SET*.

Comment: Thanks @for_stack. I think you're right. I just tested `zinterstore` on my local machine. For a set with 5000 members, the `zinterstore` will lock the whole set for almost 5ms. It's not acceptable for high concurrent read scene. But one `sscan` call can only take 15s, it's much safer for online operation although the total time-consuming seems longer.